# Programa para saber si un conjunto de cartas forman un poker

Tags: pseint

Escribir una programa poker que reciba
cinco cartas de la baraja francesa e informe
(devuelva el valor lógico correspondiente) si
esas cartas forman o no un poker (es decir
que haya 4 cartas con el mismo número).

```
Dimension cartas(5)
    
suma<-0
    
Mientras suma<5 Hacer
        
Escribir "Ingresar el valor de la carta:"
        
Leer cartas(suma)
        
suma<-suma+1
    
Fin Mientras
    
Para cada carta en cartas Hacer
        
Repetido<-0
        
Para cada otracarta en cartas Hacer
            
Si carta=otracarta Entonces
                
Repetido<-Repetido+1
            
FinSi
        
FinPara
    
FinPara
    
Si Repetido>=4 Entonces
        
Escribir "Cuatro cartas tienen el mismo valor (Poker)"

SiNo

Escribir "No hay cuatro cartas con el mismo valor (No poker)"
    
Fin Si

FinAlgoritmo
```

Mi problema es que solo mide  repetido respecto al ultimo valor agregado, no respecto a todos los valores. Alguien sabe como arreglarlo?

Comment: Buenas, bienvenido al sitio, ¿le has echado un ojo a [tour] y [ask]? Este sitio no está dedicado a proporcionar ejercicios resueltos, sino a ayudar a resolver problemas de código concretos. Si no hay código, no hay ayuda. ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora?